# Writing file manager for Android with root rights

Tags: android

I am writing web interfaced file manager for Android. It works really decent I can navigate over Android file system using web browser. However here is one problem, the manager can't step in certain directories, for example if I step into '/cache', method File("/cache").listFiles() return null. I can imagine that the problem leads to permissions. However I know that there is root file manager application, so certainly this problem can be addressed. Could somebody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383415/syntax-for-shell-command-in-android-app) answer, you need to start a subprocess with root permissions and then execute the shell commands via Java I\O.