# Syntax for shell command in Android app

Tags: android, shell, root, busybox

I am trying to run

```
String command = "su -c 'busybox ls /data'";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

in my app, but it seems like the syntax is somehow wrong. I have no problem running it from the terminal emulator app on the phone, though, so I just can't understand why it is not working when called from within my app.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Does your app have superuser privileges? App permissions are different from terminal permissions.

Comment: My knowledge is limited, but I had understood that an app can't have superuser privileges, only spawn processes that do. Btw the Superuser app notifies me that root privileges have been granted if I run say "su -c id", and the output is correct.. What do you suggest? Thanks a lot

Comment: Not exactly sure what is wrong. However, there seems to be a lot of other topics on stackoverflow that might help you if you search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216071/how-to-run-multiple-shell-commands-through-an-app-in-android. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896618/read-command-output-inside-su-process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUND! Thanks to the link suggested by [onit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897868/onit) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896618/read-command-output-inside-su-process). See the code below: for superuser shell commands to work properly, you first need to create a superuser shell and assign it to a process, then write and read on it's input and output streams respectively.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
//from here all commands are executed with su permissions
stdin.writeBytes("ls /data\n"); // \n executes the command
InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_LEN];
int read;
String out = new String();
//read method will wait forever if there is nothing in the stream
//so we need to read it in another way than while((read=stdout.read(buffer))>0)
while(true){
    read = stdout.read(buffer);
    out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
    if(read<BUFF_LEN){
        //we have read everything
        break;
    }
}
//do something with the output
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function below:

```
public void shellCommandRunAsRoot(String Command)
{
 try 
  {
     Process RunProcess= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
     DataOutputStream os;
     os = new DataOutputStream(RunProcess.getOutputStream()); 

     os.writeBytes(cmds+"\n");
         os.writeBytes("exit+\n");
     os.flush();

  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
     // Handle Exception 
  }    
}
```

**Usage:**

```
shellCommandRunAsRoot("pkill firefox");
```